# Calculating space complexity of string compression - Cracking the coding interview

Tags: java, string, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I am trying to understand space complexity of the following piece of code. The code compresses Strings from "aabbbb" to "a2b4". The question is Question 5, Chapter 1 from Cracking the coding interview version 5 (2013) and the code is taken from the [solutions](https://github.com/careercup/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%201/Question1_5/Question.java)

```
 public static String compressBetter(String str) {
    int size = countCompression(str);
    if (size >= str.length()) {
        return str;
    }
    StringBuffer mystr = new StringBuffer();
    char last = str.charAt(0);
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == last) {
            count++;
        } else {
            mystr.append(last);
            mystr.append(count);
            last = str.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    mystr.append(last);
    mystr.append(count);
    return mystr.toString();
}
```

where

```
public static int countCompression(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) return 0;
    char last = str.charAt(0);
    int size = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == last) {
            count++;
        } else {
            last = str.charAt(i);
            size += 1 + String.valueOf(count).length();
            count = 1;
        } 
    }
    size += 1 + String.valueOf(count).length();
    return size;
}
```

According to the author `compressBetter` has O(N) space complexity. **Why is that not O(1)**? 
In every run of `countCompression`, we hold `last`, `size` and `count` and similar for `compressBetter` (holds `countCompression` variables plus `mystr`, `last`, `count`. My understanding of space complexity is "how much memory the algorithm needs/holds at any time". In other words space complexity unlike time complexity is not cumulative.

Note that the author considers in the book only what people refer as "auxiliary space complexity" (without the space needed to store input) as in the example above. Also, afaik there is no entry in the [errata](http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com/errata.html) of the book on this.

UPDATE: My source of confusion was from the following example (Question 1.1 in the same book)

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars2(String str) {
  boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int val = str.charAt(i);
    if (char_set[val]) return false;
    char_set[val] = true;
  }
  return true;
}
```

which is O(1) despite a 256 boolean array allocation - I thought allocations don't matter in calculating space complexity. But in reality it's O(1) because the space needed is constant and independent of the input size (unlike the `mystr` Stringbuffer).

Comment: You are holding a StringBuffer that, potentially, could have a size proportional to the String's one. Can it be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just converting my previous comment into an answer: you are holding a `StringBuffer` that, potentially, could have a size proportional to the String's one. Just think about the case (the worst one) in which you have an input String with no consecutive, repeated characters.

Comment: Accepted since your comment was the first one. My confusion was actually coming from another example in the book (see update) but thanks for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the space complexity of `compressBetter`, which includes a call to `countCompression`, but also performs additional work.

While the space complexity of `countCompression` is indeed `O(1)`, `compressBetter` has linear space complexity (i.e. `O(N)`) in the worst case (where no two consecutive characters of the input `String` are equal), since it produces a `StringBuffer` of 2N characters in that case.